# Struts2 list validation

Tags: xml, validation, struts2, annotations

I am trying to validate a list of object on Struts2.

Suppose you had a class called `INVOICE`. 
It has 3 properties called: `product, quantity, price`

And I have a list of `INVOICE` called `INVOICES`.

In jsp file, if you iterate over the list , it will generate these inputs.

```
invoices[0].product
invoices[0].quantity
invoices[0].price
invoices[1].product
invoices[1].quantity
invoices[1].price
```

Now after submission, I need to validate these values.

As you can see, Struts2 no longer support collection validation.
http://www.opensymphony.com/webwork/api/com/opensymphony/xwork/validator/validators/CollectionFieldValidator.html

I found a way to do it with annotations. Something like

```
@RequiredStringValidator(message="Product name is required")
public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}
```

But I am not allowed to put validation annotations on bean class due to coding standard of the project. Because I need to keep MESSAGES on properties file.

I read that I could do this validation with VisitorValidation as mentioned here.
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.2/docs/using-visitor-field-validator.html

But I couldn't understand how to do this by seeing those examples.

Is there any way to do it with using only validation XMLs? Thank you

**ANSWER:**

I did it with VisitorFieldValidator, and I still had problems as I commented on correct answer.

The problem went away when I put `MyModel-validation.xml` in my model package.

As the correct answer highlighted:

**manage your validations for your models in one place, where they belong, next to your model classes.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed visitor field validation would be your bet bet. Struts2 documentation is not famous as being the most comprehensive, but you can get more information on the visitor field validator [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.1/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/validator/validators/VisitorFieldValidator.html), which includes a simple example.

> The VisitorFieldValidator allows you to forward validation to object properties of your action using the object's own validation files. This allows you to use the ModelDriven development pattern and **manage your validations for your models in one place, where they belong, next to your model classes**. The VisitorFieldValidator can handle either simple Object properties, **Collections of Objects**, or Arrays.

In your action, you can place validation for the `invoices` collection as:

```
<validators>
    <field name="invoices">
        <field-validator type="visitor">
            <message></message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Then simply proceed to create a `Invoice-validation.xml` which would hold the validation logic for your `Invoice` bean and place it along with the `Invoice` class. For example:

```
<validators>
    <field name="product">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>product is required.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Comment: Suppose List<Foo> Invoices = new ArrayList<Foo>();. Should I name my file Invoices-validation.xml or Foo-validation.xml?

Comment: I am asking because, it is not intercepted on validation.

Comment: It should be `Invoice-validation.xml`. However my example missed the `message` element on the `invoices` field validation config which is required. I'll update the example. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, it gives an error that Object.property value cannot be "". It is because it did not pass through requiredstring validation. I want it to pass by validations before it reaches to bean class.

Comment: I've missed this before - why are the form elements given name like `invoices.detail[0].product`? If the `Invoice` class contains the given properties `product`, `quantity` and `price`, and the action class is having `invoices` as `List<Invoice> invoices`, the fields should be named as `invoices[0].product` and so on..

Comment: Oh I am sorry. I copied them from somewhere to show an example. The names are corrected now. Names have format you just mentioned. But I still cannot make validation work.

Comment: @batbaatar Can you explain what you meant by 'It is because it did not pass through requiredstring validation. I want it to pass by validations before it reaches to bean class.'? What happens with the visitor field validator is that it delegates validation to the logic defined for your bean. Anyway are you sure that validation is kicking in at all? (Maybe add a simple string property in your action class and try to set validation on that)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6845/discussion-between-batbaatar-and-asa)